# Initializing a struct within a struct

Tags: c++, c, struct

I am trying to initialize a struct that is within another struct with multible members. 
Say I want init a struct with 2 int members then I can use following:

```
firstStruct struct1 = { 5 , 7 };
```

But say I want to initialize the same struct but this time it is a member of another struct:

(secondStruct members are char and firstStruct)

```
secondStruct struct2 = { 'A' , { 6 , 8 } };
```

Stucts:

```
typedef struct firstStruct 
{
    int a;
    int b;  
} firstStruct;

typedef struct secondStruct
{
    firstStruct a;
    char b;
} secondStruct;
```

But this does not work. 
How do i do this?

(I have searched for other posts with this topic, but haven't found one. Maybe I have addressed the question wrong.)

Thanks!

Comment: What are the structures?

Comment: What's S1? A typedef?

Comment: Order is meaningful with structures. Swap arguments and it will work

Comment: or swap order in initialization.

Comment: "*But this does not work.*" What exactly did not work?

Comment: It worked now. I tried the same thing i a new program to specificly check this. Then it worked. But on another program i am working on it didn't. But i think maybe this is not the problem. 
Should i remove the question?

Comment: You are aware, that due to the last update to your question most (if not all) comments and answers do not make sense anymore now? I'd say you'd better roll it back.

Comment: Sorry i will just remove this question.
Thanks for answering though helped me! :)

Comment: Why not just add a comment or update, explaining that due to cosmic noise you suffered a temporary brain laps? ;-)

Comment: I did the rollback for you, for the sake of all answers and comments committed so far.

Comment: "Why not just add a comment or update, explaining that due to cosmic noise you suffered a temporary brain laps? ;-)"
hahaha!


I sent a flag to the moderators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following works for me...

```
struct firstStruct {int a, b;};

firstStruct struct1 = { 5 , 7 };

struct secondStruct {char a; firstStruct b;};

secondStruct struct2 = { 'A' , { 6 , 8 } };
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
secondStruct struct2 = {{ 6 , 8} , 'A'};
```

Order matters.

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrectly ordered your initialization. With structs, you need to initialize each member in the correct spot. You declared the firstStruct before the char, so you need to initialize it before the char like {{5, 7}, 'A'}.

Answer (score 0):

Normally it should work as you wrote it. The only problem i can see is that you have to meet the order of the variables...

```
struct firstStruct 
{
    int a;
    int b;  
};

struct secondStruct
{
    S1 a;
    char b;
};

secondstruct = { { 1, 2 }, 3 };
```

To initialize a struct in a struct i think it is needed to put it into brackets (allthough this is right in your example)...